# Automated Interface testing on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, automated-tests

I like using the UI Recorder in Xcode for testing a UI in the simulator.  However, that I know of, UI Recorder doesn't work on the device.  Is there a similar tool for automating UI testing on the device?

Answer (score 4):

Gorilla Logic recently open-sourced FoneMonkey, a true record/playback functional testing tool for the iPhone that runs on both the simulator and device. You can check it out at http://www.gorillalogic.com/fonemonkey.

Answer (score 0):

Without saying too much, you should look at the iPhone OS 4.0 SDK betas if you're a registered iPhone developer.